# SVA: Verify stable signal in different clock domain

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

My problems is perfectly described in the following paper ["Asynchronous Behaviors Meet Their Match with SystemVerilog Assertions"](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d257/22fa4bdd0075eba396e2ffe47db9151d3a88.pdf):

> Consider  the  scenario  in Figure 8 where the strobe signal is generated in the src_clk domain and must be stable for at least 3 cycles in the dst_clk domain.  An assertion must check that the strobe signal remains stable but also that it has  the  adequate  setup  and  hold  time  to  be  sampled  in  the dst_clk domain.

[Figure 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbFjb.png)

The author then suggest the following assertion to overcome this problem:

```
assert property (
    @(posedge src_clk) $rose(strobe) |-> (
        strobe[*1:$] ##1 1 )
    ) intersect (
        ##1 @(posedge dst_clk) strobe[*3]
        ##1 @(posedge src_clk) 1
    )
 );
```

My problem is that both Cadence incisive 15.20 and Synopsys VCS 2014.10 complains about the use of multiple clocks inside an intersect:

> Incisive 15.20: Invalid operator and/or operands in multi-clock context.
>
> Synopsys VCS 2014.10: Single-clocked sequence expected in right operand of 'intersect' operator, multi-clocked sequence found.

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/wGE

It does however work when I compile using Aldec Riviera Pro 2017.02, so I'm guessing this is just a tool limitation.

Are there any other alternative ways of achieving this?

Comment: Can you just write in brief about the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I find it helpful to use glue logic to avoid complex properties.

In this case I'd count dst_clk clocks and do this:

```
unsigned reg [7:0] dst_clk_conter_width;
parameter counter_width = 256;

always @(posedge dst_clk) 
  dst_clk_counter <= dst_clk_counter +1;

property prop;
  @(posedge src_clk or posedge dst_clk)
  $rose(strobe) |-> 
    (1,strobe_rise_dst_clk_num = dst_clk_counter) 
    ##[1:$] strobe
    ##1 strobe && (dst_clk_counter  = (strobe_rise_dst_clk_num + 3) % counter_width)
endproperty
```

Explanation:

first line captures current counter value, second line makes sure strobe doesn't drop and last line checks that we passed 3 dst clocks already